# Why NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains returns an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why does NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains return an NSArray instead of a NSString with the path found?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on NSSearchPathDirectory and NSSearchPathDomainMask, it is possible that there are multiple directories. For example, i can have an Applications Folder in my Home Directory, which is my User Domain. And Also have an Applications folder in the System Domain. And an application folder in the Network Domain. SO if i do this:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);
```

It will return me an array of paths. One for the path of Applications folder in User Domain, one for the folder in System Domain and one in the network Domain.

Comment: Great, thanxs Shanti !

Answer (score 3):

This is from [Foundation Release Notes (10.8 and earlier)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/):

> In OS X v10.5 "Leopard" it is possible to have multiple versions of
>   the Developer Tools software (Xcode, Interface Builder, etc.)
>   installed on your system at one time. It is also possible to have them
>   installed in a location that is not rooted at the "/Developer" path in
>   the filesystem. As a result, the directories returned from
>   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains by passing the
>   NSDeveloperApplicationDirectory or NSDeveloperDirectory constants may
>   not return something which corresponds to the actual location of the
>   Developer Tools that are installed.

Also note that the method accepts a domain *mask*, so it's possible to have different directories for each of the domains.

I *believe* (I'm not certain) that it will only ever return multiple under OSX, and under iOS it will only ever return a single value.