# Does NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSSearchPathDirectory directory, NSSearchPathDomainMask ); ever return multiple values on iOS

Tags: objective-c

Does the following method ever return multiple values when used on iOS, and if so, do you have an example of when this happens and how to know which element is the one you asked for?

```
NSArray* NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSSearchPathDirectory directory, NSSearchPathDomainMask domainMask, BOOL expandTilde );
```

I am wondering because I am calling it with the parameters for getting a path to the Documents directory (see below), and assuming it returns an array with only one element.  It is working just fine, but it occurred to me that I might need to make sure I will never get more than one element back.  And if I do get more than one, I wondered how I would know which one is the one I asked for?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = paths[0];
```

Comment: There is a partial answer to this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364257/why-nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-returns-an-nsarray

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that on iOS you'll only ever get a single element in the returned array.

I believe it returns an array rather than a single value as it's used by OS X too and tries to be as general purpose as possible. On OS X it can potentially return multiple elements, representing the user's documents directory, the computer's documents directory, and so on, according to the domain mask.

As an aside, note that Apple recommends using the `NSFileManager` methods `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` and `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` instead, stating that URLs are preferred over path strings.